# GUI library for elderly people?

Tags: user-interface

I'm trying to develop a simple program in python (but this is not a requirement, I can switch to another language if worthwhile) and I'd like to make it very usable by elderly people, is there some GUI library already available?

Answer (score 1):

Well, which OS platform are we standing in? If you are in linux or windows and using C# take a look at MonoDevelop. If in linux, I would stick with QT LAF and there's also GTK too.

Now, if I was in your position I would start making prototypes of the program and presenting them to the ederly, survey them through the process and make best of their inputs. It's not an easy task but it will do the work at the end of the process. Keep it simple and don't try to clutter up the ui design.

Answer (score 0):

if your making a seperate GUI for elderly people it's probably best you make it yourself from whatever existing code/libraries you have.

Like increasing the element and text sizes, and increasing the contrast. But not too much that you make the majority feel patronised.

Answer (score 0):

Most GUI libs support some kind of widgets that can be used for people that have some problem with their eyes or such. However, i don't think that there is a library that is particularly targetted to that. Hence, i would use GTK or Qt. In the end, it comes down to how you design your GUI.